# How can I rectify this situation? Why am I getting the error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date_utc'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv("Nov2015.csv", encoding =('ISO-8859-1'))
pd.set_option('display.max_row', None)
df


    Date_utc    UTC       Height
0   11/1/2015   5:40 AM     0.5
1   11/1/2015   11:36 AM    2.5
2   11/1/2015   5:20 PM     0.9
3   11/1/2015   11:49 PM    2.6
4   11/2/2015   5:49 AM     0.9
5   11/2/2015   12:27 PM    2.4
6   11/2/2015   6:13 PM     1.2
7   11/3/2015   12:43 AM    2.4
8   11/3/2015   6:51 AM     1.0
9   11/3/2015   1:29 PM     2.3
10  11/3/2015   7:19 PM     1.4
11  11/4/2015   1:52 AM     2.3
12  11/4/2015   8:01 AM     1.2
13  11/4/2015   2:44 PM     2.2
14  11/4/2015   8:38 PM     1.4

combined = df.Date_utc.str.cat(df.UTC, sep=' ')
pd.to_datetime(combined)
df['datetime_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(combined)
df1 = df.set_index('datetime_utc').resample('15min').mean().interpolate('cubic', order=3)
df1
```

Comment: at which line exactly are you egtting this error

Comment: you need to provide code so that people can reproduce you problem. If they dont have the data file they cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check for nonvisible leading characters. Maybe your CSV has some spaces before the feature name, like
' Date_utc' instead of 'Date_utc'.

Comment: Thank you indeed the issue was with my CSV file. It was the actual formatting of the excel file. This was rectified and the code now works.